# I keep getting an empty result when trying to webscrape

Tags: python

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
response = requests.get("https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions")

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
questions = soup.select(".question-summary")
print(questions)
```

with this code I keep getting the result - []

If I add a [0] to the print(questions[0]), I get the error - IndexError: list index out of range

Any ideas? I've tried really hard to try and solve this my self but nothing seems to be working for me. I'm new to python so maybe missing some modules or something?

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, but why on earth aren't you using the [Stackoverflow API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs)?

Comment: I was just following a tutorial from codingwithmosh, like i said im new ;(

Comment: Hmm. Maybe try `questions = soup.select(".s-post-summary--content-excerpt")`. There doesn't seem to be any `question-summary` class in the HTML at all.

Comment: `soup.select(".question-summary")` That will select items with `class="question-summary"`.  But there are no such items.  I see lots of items with a similar-looking id, such as `id="question-summary-73709452"`.  But that's an id, not a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no elements in the response that I could find that actually have the class `question-summary`, so it's not surprising you get no results.

There are elements like these:

```html
<div id="question-summary-73709434" class="s-post-summary js-post-summary" data-post-id="73709434" data-post-type-id="1">
```

Which you could get with:

```
soup.select('.s-post-summary')
```

But you were likely after the text of the summary, something like:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get("https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions")

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
for element in soup.select('.s-post-summary--content-excerpt'):
    print(element.text.strip())
```

Comment: I will try this later tonight thank you, I did try it on my father's website and I was able to select title etc so it may just be that the tutorial I'm following is out of date inregards the html coding on stackoverflow